# Is there a way to create primary index on Teradata table with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: sqlalchemy, teradata

I can't seem to create an index when creating a Teradata volatile table with SQLAlchemy.

```
import teradatasqlalchemy 
import sqlalchemy as db

from teradatasqlalchemy import DATE, FLOAT
from teradatasqlalchemy.dialect import TDCreateTablePost as post
#from teradatasqlalchemy.compiler import TDCreateTablePost as post

from sqlalchemy.sql.schema import Table, Column
from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateTable

td_engine = db.create_engine('teradatasql://edwprod/?logmech=ldap&user=xxxx&password=yyyy')

metadata = db.MetaData()

temp_table = db.Table(
"temp_table",
metadata,
Column("calndr_dt", DATE),
Column("records", FLOAT),
teradata_post_create=post().primary_index(unique=True, cols=["calndr_dt"]),
extend_existing=True,
)

print(CreateTable(temp_table).compile(td_engine))
```

Results of print() statement, which seems to not include primary index:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table (
    calndr_dt DATE, 
    records FLOAT
)
```

**Packages:**

SQLAlchemy         1.3.16
teradatasql        16.20.0.60
teradatasqlalchemy 16.20.0.8

In [previous versions](https://downloads.teradata.com/tools/articles/teradata-sqlalchemy-introduction), seemed to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword starts with the dialect name.

```
temp_table = db.Table(
"temp_table",
metadata,
Column("calndr_dt", DATE),
Column("records", FLOAT),
teradatasql_post_create=post().primary_index(unique=True, cols=["calndr_dt"]),
extend_existing=True,
)
```

Note that this isn't actually a VOLATILE table, it's a normal (permanent) table.